# Content Security Policy invalidating login session when site accessed from an external link

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, content-security-policy

I have a fairly standard Node Express user authentication configuaration. Express-session, cookie-parser are used for sessions / cookies and passport to handle authentication.

I recently added a content security policy to all routes, and it's messing with user sessions. Navigating the site internally is fine. If you manually type a url into the browser, also good - it will remember your logged in session.

However, if you access the site via a bookmark, or follow a link from a 3rd party website, the user is thrown out and forced to log in again. If I disable the content security policy, everything is fixed.

Can anyone advise on why this happens, or what to investigate, as I'm a bit in the dark as to how it could be happening.

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-b2bd8bb3d70af06062931f9217eeec75'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:;
```

Answer (score 1):

`default-src 'self'` set all these below to `'self'`:

- child-src
- connect-src
- font-src
- frame-src
- img-src
- manifest-src
- media-src
- object-src
- prefetch-src
- script-src
- script-src-elem
- script-src-attr
- style-src
- style-src-elem
- style-src-attr
- worker-src

I would add them all manually one by one and see which one of these introduce the issue you are having. After this you can remove them all again and add the whitelisting you need.

A good practice aswell is too add a [report-uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri) to fetch all the times you get blocked. Maybe in the report there is aswell some more usefull information. You can aswell enable a ['report-only' mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only) until you are confident the issue you are having is resolved. Another resource I can suggest is the [CSP evaluator from Google](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/); it suggestions are really useful.

Hope this answer helps you find why your users get logged out!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Going through that helped me confirm it actually was nothing to do with the security policy, so I did get there in the end.

Comment: No problem. Reading your post I already suspected it had nothing to do with CSP. But as changes to this policy can have affect on alot of things you can never be completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this was a bad question...
The cause was that in the same commit, that the content-security-policy was originally added, I also set the cookie sameSite property to true. It was a mistake of me to not separate my commits better. Problem solved...